# Frames to pop when testing react native android in app billing

Tags: android, react-native, in-app-billing, android-billing

When i'm testing my app with a real product i get the error:

{FramesToPop: 1, code: "EUNSPECIFIED"}

I'm using react-native with react-native-billing

I have the following code:

```
async pay(productId) {
        await InAppBilling.close();
        try {
            await InAppBilling.open();
            if (!await InAppBilling.isPurchased(productId)) {
                const details = await InAppBilling.purchase(productId);
            }
            const transactionStatus = await InAppBilling.getPurchaseTransactionDetails(productId);
            const productDetails = await InAppBilling.getProductDetails(productId);
            this.setState({payment : productDetails})
        } catch (err) {
            this.setState({error : 'Der skete en fejl - prøv venligst igen'})
        } finally {
            await InAppBilling.consumePurchase(productId);
            await InAppBilling.close();
            if (this.props.file.type == "video") {
                this.uploadFile()
            }
            else if (this.props.file.type == "letter") {
                this.saveLetter()
            }
            else {
                this.sendTestament()
            }
        }
    }
```

If i run the pay function again, it succeds.

How can i resolve this?

Kenneth